# Regex to get uri stem (path) from uri with optional end character

Tags: regex

This should be simple but I can't seem to get it exactly right. I need to extract the uri stem/path only from a uri where it could end with a **'/'** or not and have a query string or not.

So use cases are as follows

> - /shopping/cart ----> /shopping/cart
> - /shopping/cart/ ----> /shopping/cart
> - /shopping/cart/?param1=val1&param2=val2 ----> /shopping/cart
> - /shopping/cart?param1=val1&param2=val2 ----> /shopping/cart

So far I have tried `^(\/.\*)\/ and ^(\/.\*)\/?.` I also would prefer to stay away from double groupings if at all possible

Comment: If you are writing code in C#, then you can use the [`Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to shred the URI.

Comment: This is through a tool that uses POSIX regex syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **positive lookahead** assertion ([more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) to look for the question mark:

```
^(/.*)(?=\?)
```

Comment: I'm assuming you accidently forgot to escape the initial '/' but even when I add that in this only works for again use cases 3 and 4, And it also includes the last '/' in the result for use case 3

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex

```
(^\/.*)\/\?
```

For More [reference](https://regex101.com/r/wB9cE7/1).

Comment: This only works for use case 3 and 4 above and it includes the last '/' for use case 3 which I do not want in the result. I am trying to find a single expression to use on all 4 use cases and that will return everything UP TO the last '/' that may or may not be there.